# What Biblical support for praying to the saints is usually cited by those Christians who practice that?

Tags: prayer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Praying to people outside the Trinity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11/praying-to-people-outside-the-trinity)
>   [What is the Basis for the solicitation of prayers from dead saints](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/767/what-is-the-basis-for-the-solicitation-of-prayers-from-dead-saints)

I understand that those who practice praying to the saints rely heavily on either their own experience in this regard or on the experience of others who likewise practiced praying to the saints in their lives. However, they may also have some support from the Bible for this practice. What places from the Bible do such Christians view as indicating the validity of this practice?

Comment: also related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/767/what-is-the-basis-for-the-solicitation-of-prayers-from-dead-saints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is what DRV suggest. (all Bible quotes in RSV)

Moses and Samuel can intercede:

> Then the LORD said to me, "Though Moses and Samuel stood before me, yet my heart would not turn toward this people. Send them out of my sight, and let them go! (Jer. 15:1)

Jeremiah *does* intercede:

> This is a man who loves the brethren and prays much for the people and the holy city, Jeremiah, the prophet of God. (2 Macc. 15:14)

Further Raphael hears and intercedes:

> And so, when you and your daughter-in-law Sarah prayed, I brought a reminder of your prayer before the Holy One; and when you buried the dead, I was likewise present with you.  (Tobit 12:12)

(There are misc. references in Revelation of John to saints praying in heaven, the DRV references this:

> And when he had taken the scroll, the four living creatures and the twenty-four elders fell down before the Lamb, each holding a harp, and with golden bowls full of incense, which are the prayers of the saints; (Rev. 5:8)

The efficacy of these prayers can be seen:

> And the LORD appeared to him the same night and said, "I am the God of Abraham your father; fear not, for I am with you and will bless you and multiply your descendants **for my servant Abraham's sake**."

I don't really see that much which needs to be expounded on after that.

Comment: @cwallenpoole - Perhaps, I wasn't clear enough in the way I formulated my question, but I was requesting Biblical support for the practice of praying to the saints, not the Biblical support for the fact that those saints can still pray to God even after their physical death. As far as I can see, all the references that you have cited here are pointing to the fact that the dead saints, as well as some angels, can still pray to God. However, your refrences say nothing about the living believers praying to them.

Comment: @ brilliant If the dead saints and angels can pray to God, & hear us, then talking to them and asking for their intercession is like asking a friend of mine to pray for me or asking the prayer group at Church to pray for the needs of someone I know. We do not "pray" to saints in the same sense that we "pray" to God the Father, Son & Holy Spirit.Only God is ultimately in charge of the Universe & all Creation. Fellow believers in Christ - both living & dead - are all part of the communion of oneness thru Jesus Christ... we don't"pray" TO each other in the same way.

Comment: @ brilliant, I also think you don't "get it" that Catholics view Holy Tradition as equally valid as you view proof-texting and citations from the Bible. I think this concept of communion and praying with the Saints is a cultural/worldview difference that may be difficult for you to appreciate and understand, and that's okay.